# how to check if string contain numbers?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery validation method and I want to check if string(firstname or lastname) contain numbers
my code:

```
<html>
<head>

  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link href="runnable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Load jQuery and the validate plugin -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Form Validation code -->
  <script>

  // When the browser is ready...
  $(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            agree: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Register here</h1>

  <!--  The form that will be parsed by jQuery before submit  -->
  <form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div class="label">First Name</div><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Last Name</div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Email</div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
    <div class="label">Password</div><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
    <div style="margin-left:140px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

how to do that??
I want if someone fill his/her first name or last name with numbers or it contain numbers like (1234 or john1234 or 1234john or jo1234hn ..ect) get massage that name is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without regular expressions and adding a custom method to the jQuery validator like

```
$.validator.addMethod("textOnly",
    function (value, element) {

        var numArray = 
            ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
        var containsNumber = false;

        $.each(value.split(''), function () {
            if (numArray.indexOf($(this)[0]) > -1) {
                containsNumber = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        return !containsNumber;
    }, 
   );
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHF7H/3/)

Comment: @M0136466, no problem and sorry about broken fiddles ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect whether a string contains digits using the following snippet:

```
if(str.matches(".*\\d.*")){
   // The string has a number, do whatever logic you need here.
} 
else{
   // The string does not have numbers in it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kenneth said str.matches but it should be str.match

```
if(str.match(".*\\d.*")){
   // The string has a number, do whatever logic you need here.
} 
else{
   // The string does not have numbers in it.
}
```